# How to properly install a module in python?

Tags: python

I 'm new to python, and I need some help.
At first i install pyperclip using command window: "pip3 install pyperclip". The command window responsed that I have downloaded the module successfully.
However I can not use pyperclip in my code. When I coded "import pyperclip", there was an error: "No module name pyperclip..."
I then changed the directory of the command window direct to the address of Python, but nothing seem to work.
I use PyCharm for my coding. 
Hope you can hep me solve this problem.
[Python responsed "No module name pyperclip..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6gYE.png)

[It clearly that I have download the module.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSttp.png)

Comment: Locate the  `pyperclip` location  and once do check whether the path to `pyperclib` location is in python sys path or not. You can check by `import sys` `print(sys.path)`. if the `pyperclip` isn't in it then do sys.path.append(`pyperclip actual path`)

Answer (score 1):

Find path to python which you are using and then do something like:

```sh
path/to/python -m pip install pyperclip
```

Or better use conda or pipenv

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have installed the package for another interpreter, one that is not used by your current project.
How to install modules for a particular interpreter in PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

You can also select the interpreter for the particular configuration (setup used for running a script):
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html